# web.xml security-constraints interfering with each other

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, security, web.xml

I've defined the following security-constraints in the application's web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict access to XHTML files</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>XHTML files</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

And:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Disable DELETE, PUT and TRACE</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Restricted methods</web-resource-name>
        <description>Disable DELETE, PUT and TRACE</description>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>
```

The first one stops working when I add the second one. Looking at both URL patterns and HTTP methods, one should expect that both constraints would work correctly, or am I missing something here?